# C# Build simple server with event when new client connected

Tags: c#

I tried to build a simple server in c# which wait for connections from clients. If a new client connects it makes a new Thread where it read from the client and send a message back to the client, that the server received the message from the client. My problem is that I try to raise an event when a new client connected to the server, but I just don't get what I should subscribe to.

Here is my code:

```
namespace ChatServer
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    public static event EventHandler<NewClientConnectedEventArgs>NewClientConnected;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 80);
        listener.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            //listener += NewClientConnected(null, new NewClientConnectedEventArgs(client));
            //FireNewClientHasConnected(null, eventargs);
        }
    }

    public static void MakeNewConnection(TcpClient client)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(NewClient));
        thread.Start(client);
    }

    public static void NewClient(object data)
    {
        TcpClient client = (TcpClient)data;

        string adress = client.Client.AddressFamily.ToString();

        Console.WriteLine("{0} has connected!", adress);

        NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();

        while (true)
        {
            byte[] receivedbuffer = new byte[8192];
            int receivedbytes;

            receivedbytes = ns.Read(receivedbuffer, 0, receivedbuffer.Length);

            string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receivedbuffer, 0, receivedbytes);
            string newmessage = "The server received: " + message;

            byte[] sendBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(newmessage);
            ns.Write(sendBuffer, 0, sendBuffer.Length);
        }
    }

    protected static void FireNewClientHasConnected(object sender, NewClientConnectedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (NewClientConnected != null)
        {
            MakeNewConnection(args.Client);  
        }
    }
}
```

The part where I have the problem is the part which I comment out. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The call listener.AcceptTcpClient() blocks until a client connected. So just fire the event after the listener accepted the client.

```
class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 80);
            listener.Start();
            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                MakeNewConnection(client);
            }
        }

        public static void MakeNewConnection(TcpClient client)
        {
            var thread = new Thread(NewClient);
            thread.Start(client);
        }

        public static void NewClient(object data)
        {
            var client = (TcpClient)data;

            string adress = client.Client.AddressFamily.ToString();

            Console.WriteLine("{0} has connected!", adress);

            NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();

            while (true)
            {
                byte[] receivedbuffer = new byte[8192];

                int receivedbytes = ns.Read(receivedbuffer, 0, receivedbuffer.Length);

                string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receivedbuffer, 0, receivedbytes);
                string newmessage = "The server received: " + message;

                byte[] sendBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(newmessage);
                ns.Write(sendBuffer, 0, sendBuffer.Length);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: So I don't need anything to subscribe to the event? And I also don't need to check if the event is null, because nothing is subscribed than? Im a bit confused.

Comment: As long as you do not want to expose the client to other classes than Program, leave the event away and directly call MakeNewConnection()